# lerna link vs. lerna bootstrap

Tags: javascript, lerna, monorepo

I have a Lerna project which until recently was using `lerna bootstrap --hoist`. This worked well but I found the `devDependencies` in the many sub folders were mostly identical. Upgrading to Lerna v3 I read about `lerna link convert.`

Does lerna link convert simply move all the sub folder `devDependencies` into root, and sub folders scan the parent `node_modules` to load them (a feature of NPM)? I've noticed dependencies within the sub-folders are changed to "file://" instead of the private npm store which indicates once published and consumed they wouldn't be loaded.

Also if `lerna bootstrap` is dropped then `dependencies` within the sub modules aren't installed. What method is used to resolve this?

Comment: Four questions in one is definitively too broad, please review [ask]

Comment: Ok, cut down to 2 (related)

Comment: what do you mean with `Also if lerna bootstrap is dropped` ?

Answer (score -4):

My recommendation would be to take advantage of Yarn Workspaces' ability to "hoist" packages to the root level. This will prevent having identical dependencies nested in your packages.

[Here's a completed example](https://github.com/Hy-Vee/lerna-yarn-workspaces-monorepo) and the [associated tutorial.](https://medium.com/hy-vee-engineering/creating-a-monorepo-with-lerna-yarn-workspaces-cf163908965d)

Comment: why was this downvoted? The "big boys" like the jest repo uses lerna + yarn workspaces